# ScriptManager not found by UpdatePanel if loaded in BasePage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

Platform: asp.net 4.0

I load scriptmanager from a baseclass for custom cdn handling and scripts inserting in pages and other custom things.

The problem is that when I insert an UpdatePanel it doesn't find the script manager because updatepanel search for it to early.

Is there a solution that does not imply removing ScriptManager from the basePage.

this class is from our custom utility dll

```
public abstract class OurFrameworkBasePage:Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentScriptManager = BuildScriptManager();
        Form.Controls.AddAt(0, CurrentScriptManager);
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private ScriptManager BuildScriptManager()
    {
        return new ScriptManager
        {
            //some scriptmanager settings
        };
    }

    protected ScriptManager CurrentScriptManager { get; set; }
}
```

this is site specific basepage

```
public abstract class SiteBasePage:OurFrameworkBasePage
{
    //some custom methods and utility for a specific site
}
```

the default.aspx page

```
<html>
<head runat="server"><title></title></head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltr"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnOkClick" ID="btnOk" Text="ok"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
       </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you have control over your framework class, as this will fix your issue:

```
protected override ControlCollection CreateControlCollection()
{
    CurrentScriptManager = BuildScriptManager();
    ControlCollection pageControls = base.CreateControlCollection();
    pageControls.AddAt(0, CurrentScriptManager);
    return pageControls;
}
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    Form.Controls.AddAt(0, CurrentScriptManager);
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Needs to be in both places. First, in CreateControlCollection so that it is created along with all the other controls. Second, in OnInit, because the ScriptManager needs to reside in a form with runat="server"

Comment: Great! i did not think about CreateControlCollection. in the meantime i found another solution, and i'll post it for reference

Answer (score 1):

GuthMD's solution is a great one.

in the meantime i found another solution that accomplish different needs and i write there for reference.

My solution imply that if you want to handle postback with updatePanel you have to put scriptmanager tag in aspx page otherwise scriptmanger will be inserted programmatically for scripts references

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentScriptManager = BuildScriptManager();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    private ScriptManager BuildScriptManager()
    {
        ScriptManager rtn;
        var script = Items[typeof (ScriptManager)];
        if (script == null)
        {
            rtn = new ScriptManager
                      {
                          EnablePartialRendering = false
                      };
            Form.Controls.AddAt(0, rtn);
        }
        else
        {
            rtn = (ScriptManager) script;
        }

        rtn.EnablePageMethods = false;
        rtn.AjaxFrameworkMode = AjaxFrameworkMode.Disabled;
        rtn.EnableCdn = true;
        return rtn;
    }
```